# OneSignal - Ionic SDK - Missing Capability Issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, onesignal

I've setup OneSignal Ionic SDK to work with my Ionic 3 project.

Its finally registering devices in the console. However, when I archive and export the project from  xCode to desktop, then run the project on a real device in browserstack (since emulator/simulator is not supported) - I get the following error (in console under users):

```
(Missing Push Capability)
```

The push capability is definitely there, as its enabled and I had been using Firebase Cloud Messaging - though had to migrate.

I'm just wondering if I'm missing anything here or is this a bug with OneSignal?

Many Thanks,
Kieran

Answer (score 1):

that's the cause of the App Store rejection. If your ad-hoc provisioning profile has the aps-environment key, it means your app is configured correctly in the Apple Provisioning Portal. All you need to do is delete the App Store distribution profile on your local machine, then re-download and install the distribution profile from the Provisioning Portal. This new one should contain the aps-environment key.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its not being rejected in the app store as far as I know. I'm just testing no BrowserStack and OneSignal. So you think that by restoring a new Distribution profile, it would help OneSignal to find users and send?